# Induction with two unknown variables

Tags: induction

I have been at this problem for a while now, and I cannot wrap my head around it. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

The runtime for a sorting algorithm can be described by $a_{1} = 3$ and

[image]

I need to prove, that

[image]

For all $n, k \in Z^{+}$

I've tried to do the basestep, but even here I'm not sure if it's correct. I hope someone can help with the induction step as well.

**Basecase:**

$n, k = 2$

$a_{2} =a_{2/2} + a_{2/2} + 3*2+1 = 13 $

$3* 2 * 2^2 + 4 * 2^2 -1 = 39$

$a_n \leq 3 * k * 2^k + 4 * 2^k - 1$ applies for the basebase, since $13 \leq 39$ is true.

**Inductionstep:**

?

Comment: We just saw this one, but I can't find the duplicate.

Comment: You just need to induct on $k$.  The base case should be $k=1$  Then note that $n\le2^k\implies\left\lceil{ n\over2}\right\rceil\le2^{k-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to prove by induction over $k$ that for all $1 \leq n \leq 2^k$, $a_n \leq 3k2^k+2^{k+2}-1$.